# Jquery UI override styles

Tags: css, jquery-ui, overriding

I am using JQuery UI 1.9.1 custom CSS file, and client requested that the active state of UI buttons looks like the hover state of the buttons. I thought it was going to be as simple as:

```
    #myId .ui-state-active { css of hover state }
```

This works but it obviously takes a lot of CPU time, since everything slows down, and CPU fan starts to work really hard.

Any ideas?

Edit: I am using buttonset, not button, but that wouldn't make a big difference would it? I was wrong when I wrote button.

Comment: "it obviously takes a lot of CPU time, since everything slows down, and CPU fan starts to work really hard." There's no reason a line of CSS would throttle the CPU. Something else is wrong.

Comment: Try detaching the button from everything (onclick="return false") and see what happens.

Comment: I am using buttonset, as I edited my post, that maybe has to do something with all of my problems?

Comment: I am not sure what happened, I added more specific selector (which I tried earlier), and it works, but I can still hear my fan starts to rotate faster on i5 3210, really strange behavior.

Comment: Unfortunatly my previous solution didn't work, unwanted behavior returned shortly after...

Comment: Something else is wrong, connected lists is making some trouble, but only when I click on one of those buttonsets. When connected option is removed from sortable everything works smoothly, but that must be solved somehow.